# Manage users in SQLMembershipProvider on website migrated to Azure

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, sqlmembershipprovider

I migrated a site to Azure that had run on SqlMembershipProvider for years. Whenever we needed to manage a user we used the Website Administration Tool (WSAT) in Visual Studio 2005 that was installed on the server. It seems that WSAT was removed from VS several years ago. I've been Googling and have yet to find a solid answer as to how I'm to manage users now under this scenario in Azure. Am I expected to write my own administration backend? Is there something built into Azure that I can't find? Or, better yet, is there a third party package I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I expected to write my own administration backend? Is there something built into Azure that I can't find?

The WSAT is not built-in support in Azure Web App. To manager your users and roles, you need to create your own Website Administration Tool and publish it to Azure Web App.

Here is a document which describe how to build a Web Site Administration Tool in ASP.NET.

[Create Your Own Web Site Administration Tool in ASP.NET](http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Web-Site-Administration-Tool.aspx)